# How to load unlocked workspace using Perfoce?

Tags: perforce

Recently required access to a workspace which was locked and was not even visible to me in the depot in perforce. Now I got Read access to the workspace, but still I cannot see the workspace in perforce UI. I tried to refresh depot but it didn't work. Do I need to change anything in `client config` file?

Comment: A superuser can unlock the workspace for you. Are you trying to use this workspace? Do you know if you are prohibited from seeing the files to which it is mapped?

Comment: Perhaps the "host" field in the workspace is set to the original user's laptop or workstation, and is thus preventing you from using it on your laptop or workstation. You can modify the host field to allow it to be used from your machine (although of course any files that the original user was working on in their pending changelists are still on their own machine)